# Nikon D3200 image quality compared to D3300?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3200, nikon-d3300

I've read conflicting posts and seen no decent pictures comparing the two... Is the quality of D3200 much worse compared to that of D3300? I'm asking assuming someone who pays attention may have tried both cameras and may know... Something I have been unable to find info on.

Comment: Your choice in lenses will have a far greater impact on image quality than the difference between the D3200 and D3300.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [DxOMark](http://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Compare/Side-by-side/Nikon-D3300-versus-Nikon-D3200___928_801) the D3200 and D3300 are very, very similar. The D3300 edges out the best performance, but it's such a tiny difference that it's safe to say lens choice and technique are the bigger differentiators.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one major difference in the build of the D3200 and D3300. 
That is, the D3300 has no optical low pass filter. This should theoreticly result in better detail for fine patterns and the absence of the moire effect!

A picture comparison can be found [here](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/nikon-d3300/nikon-d3300-image-quality.htm).

In the picture below, you can see that the theory suits practice pretty well. The pink cloth is much more detailed in the D3300 (left) than in the picture taken with D3200 (right).
[image: D3300] [image: D3200]

Comment: That seems to be the main argument, but everything I could find was barely theoretical. No pic-to-pic comparisons.

Comment: I've added two pictures you can compare and a link to a more detailed comparison. 

Half a year ago I did he same research, because I was also looking at the D3200 or D3300. In the end I bought D3200 because I didn't think it was worth another €100, to have a little more detail.

Comment: Interesting... The level of details is quite a bit higher indeed, and the colors seem more vibrant. Something to think about before buying D3200. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Lack of the LPF in the D3300 means it will demonstrate *more* moire (with scenes that include repeating patterns that create moire) in exchange for the finer detail.

Answer (score -2):

I think there's a bit of clumping in the 3300 picture. The 3200 has better dynamic range. It also has phase detection which is more accurate. It's six of one and half a dozen of the other as between the two cameras.

Comment: -1: every DSLR uses phase detection, and phase detection is generally *less* accurate than contrast detection (but much faster).